# MongoDB - $substr on all strings in an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregation, designed to find values that start with a given query and then prioritize exact matches in the results. The `tags` field is an array that contains 1 or more strings.

```
results = await Post.aggregate([

    // Find all tags that begin with the given query
    { $match: { 'tags': new RegExp("^" + query, 'i') } },

    { $addFields: {
        // Add a field 'true' where one of the string values is an exact match of the query
        'exactMatch': { $eq: [ '$tags', query ] },

        // Add a field 'true' where the first 3 characters of one of the string values match the query
        'startsWith': { $eq: [ { $substr: [ '$tags', 0, 3 ] }, query ] },
    } },

    // Prioritize exact matches first
    { $sort: { 'exactMatch': -1, 'startsWith': -1 } },

    // Remove the added fields from results
    { $project: { 'exactMatch': 0, 'startsWith': 0 } }
])
```

This works perfectly when the `tags` field is a single string, however I am trying to do this now with an array of strings.

The problem lies within this line of code:

```
// Add a field 'true' where the first 3 characters of one of the string values match the query
'startsWith': { $eq: [ { $substr: [ '$tags', 0, 3 ] }, query ] },
```

Due to the `tags` field being an array, the `$substr` function is invalid and produces this error:

> MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: can't convert from BSON type array to String

How can I convert this line of code to target all values within the array, rather than the array itself?

**(Edit) Sample data, input & expected results**

With the following data:

```
[
    {
        title: 'Post1',
        content: 'This is test post 1.',
        tags: [
            'post', '12345'
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Post2',
        content: 'This is test post 2.',
        tags: [
            'post', '789'
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Post3',
        content: 'This is test post 3.',
        tags: [
            'post', '123'
        ]
    }
]
```

And an input query of "123" I would expect to see the following results:

```
[
    {
        title: 'Post3',
        content: 'This is test post 3.',
        tags: [
            'post', '123'
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Post1',
        content: 'This is test post 1.',
        tags: [
            'post', '12345'
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Would be great if you can attach the sample input and expected output documents.

Comment: @YongShun edited the post to add sample data, input & results

Comment: Nice, but would like to clarify, if substring from 0, 3 for each element in `tags` array, shouldn't the "post" will become "pos"?

Comment: @YongShun Yes, in this aggregation it would be comparing the input query to “pos” - if you searched for “pos” it would return those with tag of “post”

Comment: Okay, I think in the previous comment I misunderstand the data. Perhaps this is what you need, to work with $filter operator. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cTR2A_WCvpB)

Comment: @YongShun thanks for your demo! It looks like the startsWith field is working, but the sorting is not in the expected order - I would expect Post3 to be the top result in the query. Is this down to the sort options being incorrect or is it just matching and sorting by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised your query.

As `tags` is an array. You should work with `$filter` to filter each element in the array. And match the result whether it is not an empty array.

```js
results = await Post.aggregate([

    // Find all tags that begin with the given query
    { $match: { 'tags': new RegExp("^" + query, 'i') } },

    {
    $addFields: {
      // Add a field 'true' where one of the string values is an exact match of the query
      "exactMatch": {
        $ne: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$tags",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this",
                  query
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      },
      // Add a field 'true' where the first 3 characters of one of the string values match the query
      "startsWith": {
        $ne: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$tags",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $substr: [
                      "$$this",
                      0,
                      3
                    ]
                  },
                  query
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },

    // Prioritize exact matches first
    { $sort: { 'exactMatch': -1, 'startsWith': -1 } },

    // Remove the added fields from results
    { $project: { 'exactMatch': 0, 'startsWith': 0 } }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3HgpPPHHcO-)

Comment: You're welcome. And apologize for the delay in reviewing and writing the solution.

Comment: Not a problem at all :)